# Java unit tests failing with NoClassDefFoundError while running using mvn test but are passing using intelliJ UI

Tags: java, intellij-idea, junit

I have an enum `ProductID`,

```
import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

public enum ProductID {

.....

}
```

with corresponding test

```
public class ProductIDTest {

    @Test
    public void test1(){
        --
    }
    
    @Test
    public void test2(){
        --
    }

    @Test
    public void test3(){
        --
    }

}
```

While using green run button from intelliJ, it is passing,

[image]

but while I am running it using `mvn test`, this is failing with following error

```
[INFO] Running ProductIDTest
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/**/.m2/**/slf4j/slf4j-reload4j/1.7.36/slf4j-reload4j-1.7.36.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/**/.m2/**/ch/qos/logback/logback-classic/1.2.11/logback-classic-1.2.11.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Detected both log4j-over-slf4j.jar AND bound slf4j-reload4j.jar on the class path, preempting StackOverflowError. 
SLF4J: See also http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#log4jDelegationLoop for more details.
[TestNG] Reporter [FailedReporter passed=0 failed=0 skipped=0] failed
java.lang.NullPointerException
        java.lang.NullPointerException
        at java.util.HashMap.putMapEntries(HashMap.java:501)
        at java.util.HashMap.putAll(HashMap.java:785)
        at org.testng.xml.XmlClass.setParameters(XmlClass.java:231)
        at org.testng.reporters.FailedReporter.createXmlClasses(FailedReporter.java:199)
        at org.testng.reporters.FailedReporter.createXmlTest(FailedReporter.java:150)
        at org.testng.reporters.FailedReporter.generateXmlTest(FailedReporter.java:124)
        at org.testng.reporters.FailedReporter.generateFailureSuite(FailedReporter.java:64)
        at org.testng.reporters.FailedReporter.generateReport(FailedReporter.java:49)
        at org.testng.TestNG.generateReports(TestNG.java:1069)
        at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1012)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGExecutor.run(TestNGExecutor.java:135)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGDirectoryTestSuite.executeSingleClass(TestNGDirectoryTestSuite.java:112)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGDirectoryTestSuite.execute(TestNGDirectoryTestSuite.java:99)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGProvider.invoke(TestNGProvider.java:146)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.invokeProviderInSameClassLoader(ForkedBooter.java:383)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:344)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.execute(ForkedBooter.java:125)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:417)
[ERROR] Tests run: 3, Failures: 3, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.642 s <<< FAILURE! - in ProductIDTest
[ERROR] test1 on test1(ProductIDTest)(ProductIDTest)  Time elapsed: 0.052 s  <<< FAILURE!
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
        at org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder.<init>(StaticLoggerBinder.java:72)
        at org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder.<clinit>(StaticLoggerBinder.java:45)
        at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.bind(LoggerFactory.java:150)
        at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.performInitialization(LoggerFactory.java:124)
        at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getILoggerFactory(LoggerFactory.java:417)
        at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:362)
        at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:388)
        at ProductID.<clinit>(ProductID.java:37)
        at ProductIDTest.testGetDescription(ProductIDTest.java:11)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:59)
        at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
        at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:56)
        at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:306)
        at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner$1.evaluate(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:100)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:366)
        at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:103)
        at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:63)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$4.run(ParentRunner.java:331)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:79)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:329)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$100(ParentRunner.java:66)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:293)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:306)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:413)
        at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
        at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:115)
        at org.testng.junit.JUnit4TestRunner.start(JUnit4TestRunner.java:74)
        at org.testng.junit.JUnit4TestRunner.run(JUnit4TestRunner.java:65)
        at org.testng.TestRunner$1.run(TestRunner.java:652)
        at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1259)
        at org.testng.TestRunner.runJUnitWorkers(TestRunner.java:843)
        at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRunJUnit(TestRunner.java:681)
        at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:585)
        at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:384)
        at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:378)
        at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:337)
        at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:286)
        at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:53)
        at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:96)
        at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1187)
        at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1109)
        at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1039)
        at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1007)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGExecutor.run(TestNGExecutor.java:135)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGDirectoryTestSuite.executeSingleClass(TestNGDirectoryTestSuite.java:112)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGDirectoryTestSuite.execute(TestNGDirectoryTestSuite.java:99)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGProvider.invoke(TestNGProvider.java:146)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.invokeProviderInSameClassLoader(ForkedBooter.java:383)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:344)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.execute(ForkedBooter.java:125)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:417)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Detected both log4j-over-slf4j.jar AND bound slf4j-reload4j.jar on the class path, preempting StackOverflowError. See also http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#log4jDelegationLoop for more details.
        at org.slf4j.impl.Reload4jLoggerFactory.<clinit>(Reload4jLoggerFactory.java:55)
        ... 56 more

[ERROR] test2 on test2(ProductIDTest)(ProductIDTest)  Time elapsed: 0.001 s  <<< FAILURE!
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class ProductID
        at ProductIDTest.test2(ProductIDTest.java:24)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:59)
        at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
        at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:56)
        at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:306)
        at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner$1.evaluate(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:100)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:366)
        at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:103)
        at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:63)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$4.run(ParentRunner.java:331)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:79)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:329)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$100(ParentRunner.java:66)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:293)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:306)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:413)
        at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
        at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:115)
        at org.testng.junit.JUnit4TestRunner.start(JUnit4TestRunner.java:74)
        at org.testng.junit.JUnit4TestRunner.run(JUnit4TestRunner.java:65)
        at org.testng.TestRunner$1.run(TestRunner.java:652)
        at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1259)
        at org.testng.TestRunner.runJUnitWorkers(TestRunner.java:843)
        at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRunJUnit(TestRunner.java:681)
        at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:585)
        at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:384)
        at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:378)
        at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:337)
        at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:286)
        at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:53)
        at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:96)
        at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1187)
        at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1109)
        at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1039)
        at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1007)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGExecutor.run(TestNGExecutor.java:135)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGDirectoryTestSuite.executeSingleClass(TestNGDirectoryTestSuite.java:112)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGDirectoryTestSuite.execute(TestNGDirectoryTestSuite.java:99)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGProvider.invoke(TestNGProvider.java:146)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.invokeProviderInSameClassLoader(ForkedBooter.java:383)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:344)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.execute(ForkedBooter.java:125)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:417)

[ERROR] test3 on test3(ProductIDTest)(ProductIDTest)  Time elapsed: 0 s  <<< FAILURE!
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class ProductID
        at ProductIDTest.test3(ProductIDTest.java:17)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:59)
        at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
        at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:56)
        at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:306)
        at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner$1.evaluate(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:100)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:366)
        at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:103)
        at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:63)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$4.run(ParentRunner.java:331)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:79)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:329)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$100(ParentRunner.java:66)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:293)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:306)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:413)
        at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
        at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:115)
        at org.testng.junit.JUnit4TestRunner.start(JUnit4TestRunner.java:74)
        at org.testng.junit.JUnit4TestRunner.run(JUnit4TestRunner.java:65)
        at org.testng.TestRunner$1.run(TestRunner.java:652)
        at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1259)
        at org.testng.TestRunner.runJUnitWorkers(TestRunner.java:843)
        at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRunJUnit(TestRunner.java:681)
        at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:585)
        at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:384)
        at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:378)
        at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:337)
        at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:286)
        at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:53)
        at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:96)
        at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1187)
        at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1109)
        at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1039)
        at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1007)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGExecutor.run(TestNGExecutor.java:135)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGDirectoryTestSuite.executeSingleClass(TestNGDirectoryTestSuite.java:112)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGDirectoryTestSuite.execute(TestNGDirectoryTestSuite.java:99)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGProvider.invoke(TestNGProvider.java:146)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.invokeProviderInSameClassLoader(ForkedBooter.java:383)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:344)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.execute(ForkedBooter.java:125)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:417)

[INFO]
```

Comment: please share your pom.xml file. Also: is the class ProductID in the same project? or it is located in a project dependency?

Comment: Same project. The pom.xml is my org specific, are you looking for specific dependency version? Also I mentioned that tests are passing using intelliJ UI. I am assuming its some classpath issue.

Comment: The error `Could not initialize class ProductID` means that the JVM has at that point already tried and failed to load the class, because an exception was thrown performing static initialization (assigning values to `static` fields and running any `static { ... }` blocks) for this class. If you go back in the Maven output, is there a different error, perhaps one wrapped in an `ExceptionInInitializerError`?

Comment: Java includes detailed error stack traces; don't truncate them.

Comment: @LukeWoodward yes

Answer (score 0):

I added below in my pom.xml

```
<exclusion>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j-over-slf4j</artifactId>
</exclusion>
```

I was earlier excluding this from incorrect dependency. I used `mvn dependency:tree` to determine appropriate dependency it was coming from.